# Can't edit linked table in subform, but can edit directly in table view -- Access 2013

Tags: sql-server, database, ms-access, odbc

I have a linked table using SQL Server 2008. I have it linked in Access 2013 such that if I open the table in Access' table view, I can edit and add new records and the SQL Server reflects those changes. However, I have a subform in another form which won't let me add any new records. I can see existing records, but not add new ones.

I had this set up where the table was a local table earlier, and it worked fine. But after making the table linked, it no longer works.

When I select the subform and view the Form properties, I can see that "Data Entry" is set to No. But if I change it to Yes and then refresh the form, it changes back to No. I'm not quite sure why this is happening.

Any insight on how to get my subform working would be appreciated.

Comment: Are there any joins in the subform's data source or is it bound directly to (and only to) the linked table? If it's bound alone, is the control source of the subform the table name or a SQL Select statement?

Comment: @ChristopherD. Yeah, there are a few INNER JOINs with two other linked tables. One of those two was linked even when I was working with local tables and so I'm pretty sure that one isn't the issue. The other linked table was moved to the SQL Server along with the table I was talking about above.

Comment: If any of the INNER JOINS are relationships other than one-to-one, then you do not have an "updatable" dataset. This happens when Access cannot determine the unique row to update, due to a one-to-many type relationship. There are a few other cases where this can occur as well, take a look through this article and see if it explains your issue. If not, maybe someone else has an idea of what could be going wrong. http://www.fmsinc.com/Microsoftaccess/query/non-updateable/index.html

Comment: Hmm... they all are one-to-one. And they worked until I moved them to the SQL Server. The tables are exactly the same as before, just linked instead of local now.